# Error S3925 : Update this implementation of 'ISerializable' to conform to the recommended serialization pattern

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, sonarlint

I have the following code written in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

Since I upgraded the package NuGet SonarAnalyzer.CSharp to the version 6.0.0.2033, I've got this error :

**Error S3925   Update this implementation of 'ISerializable' to conform to the recommended serialization pattern.**

```
public class GenericException : Exception
{
    public GenericException(string message) : base(message)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public GenericException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: This is marked as duplicate with no link to the duplicate.
The link to sonarlint is also 404.

Comment: This URL should work: https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/tag/pitfall/RSPEC-3925

Comment: Solution is https://stackoverflow.com/a/65340361/315352