# Sonarcube does not like my implementation of serializable exception class

Tags: c#, sonarqube, iserializable

SonarCube shows me error "*Update this implementation of 'ISerializable' to conform to the recommended serialization pattern*" for the following exception implementation:

```
[Serializable]
public class UnrecoverableException : Exception, ISerializable
{
    public bool Ignore { get; }

    public UnrecoverableException()
    {
    }

    public UnrecoverableException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }

    protected UnrecoverableException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        Ignore= info.GetBoolean(nameof(Ignore));
    }

    public UnrecoverableException(string message, bool ignore= false) : base(message)
    {
        Ignore= ignore;
    }

    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue(nameof(Ignore), Ignore);
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
    }
}
```

not sure what's wrong here as to me it seems totally following rules described here https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/tag/pitfall/RSPEC-3925

> This rules raises an issue on types that implement `ISerializable` without following the serialization pattern recommended by Microsoft.
>
> - The `System.SerializableAttribute` attribute is missing.
> - Non-serializable fields are not marked with the `System.NonSerializedAttribute` attribute.
> - There is no serialization constructor.
> - An unsealed type has a serialization constructor that is not protected.
> - A sealed type has a serialization constructor that is not private.
> - An unsealed type has a `ISerializable.GetObjectData` that is not both public and virtual.
> - A derived type has a serialization constructor that does not call the base constructor.
> - A derived type has a `ISerializable.GetObjectData` method that does not call the base method.
> - A derived type has serializable fields but the `ISerializable.GetObjectData` method is not overridden.

Comment: I think the problem might be with this "An unsealed type has a serialization constructor that is not protected" condition. However what if I need throw this type of exception directly and hove other exceptions derived from it

Comment: I think it doesn't like the backing field for the auto-property.  I bet it isn't decorated with a serialization attribute.  What happens if you remove the property, or change it to one with an explicit backing field decorated per the rules?

Comment: issue was with protected vs public member indeed

Comment: Cool, you figured it out?  I'm interested in what the answer is.

Comment: I just made 2 separate exception classes derived from it instead of using 1 parent and 1 derived class, and made constructors protected

Comment: You can answer your own question below, you know?

Answer (score 62):

All I had to do to pass Sonarqube's analysis was add the `[Serializable]` attribute to the class and add a `protected` constructor. i.e.:

```
[Serializable]
public class BadRequestException : Exception
{
    public BadRequestException(string message) : base(message)
    {

    }

    protected BadRequestException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It helps. This answer should've more upvotes.

Comment: I get analysis warnings about non-nullable properties being uninitialized in the protected constructor. This only happens when I have nullable reference types enabled. Unfortunately, I won't have appropriate information to initialize these properties in this specific constructor. And I don't want to make them nullable because that changes the semantics of the class and affects calling code. How should I resolve?

Comment: You are fortunate. I ran into this today, and what worked for you no longer works. I have no idea what Sonarlint wants.

Comment: Yes, but then how to add a unit test so that SonarQube doesn't give you a coverage error?

Answer (score 0):

From .Net [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-user-defined-exceptions) standpoint, for custom exception, all we need to do is derive from Exception class and they further recommend to add empty, message and message + inner exception constructors.

However, Sonar cloud raises warning [S3925](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-dotnet/issues/2580) for this implementation in .Net 8. Further investigation into this requires implementing a protected constructor and override of GetObjectData as seen below. Apparently, these are now marked obsolete in .Net 8.

Finally [this](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/34893) worked for me:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyException : Exception
{
    public MyException() { }
    public MyException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public MyException(string message, Exception? innerException) : base(message, innerException) { }

    [Obsolete("", DiagnosticId = "SYSLIB0051")]
    protected MyException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }

    [Obsolete("", DiagnosticId = "SYSLIB0051")]
    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
    }
}
```